Terraform throws error provider::time::rfc3339_parse: Expected a newline or comma to mark the beginning of the next attribute
I'm trying to use provider::time::rfc3339_parse to convert the timestamp into epoch unix timestamp. When I run terraform, it seems I need to somehow escape the colons in the function. Any ideas on how to overcome that error?
I have tried using \ but I don't think that worked at all. Have tried poutting it in ${} as well.
It should just work as is.

Can you show us how and with which value(s) are you using the function?

Please provide the relevant code snippet where you are using provider::time::rfc3339_parse to help diagnose the issue.

I suspect you are using a version of Terraform earlier than Terraform v1.8.
Only Terraform v1.8 and later can call provider-contributed functions using this new syntax. Older versions of Terraform will consider it to be a syntax error, because :: was not previously accepted in that location.
